# User Id in JWT token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a

1. back-end application - ASP.NET Web API
2. front end - React.

We are using a third party for authentication and have role based access for authorization.

We found an issue where in user who is authenticated and authorized was able to change an id say documentid in GET call (/API/Document/{documentid}) and was able to view other user data.

So after researching one way is to check on the call if the owner of the document (userid) matches the userid of the logged in. Since its Web API we cannot store the userid in session, so we had to set the userid in JWT. So when logged in we set the userid in JWT and we can make a check on the calls to see if the owner of the resource matches with userid in JWT. I see some concerns adding/exposing userid in JWT, so the question is what is the best way to handle it? I can make use of username but that might add an overhead of database call to get userid or add the username in every view model.

Comment: sounds like the service should be checking the userid for the request by id at the very least...

Comment: *"I see some concerns adding/exposing userid in JWT"* – what concerns? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Userid is the primary key, I came across some posts which mentioned that it’s not safe to expose the underlying implementation details